# Detecting whether a Clojure expression is primitive

Tags: clojure, primitive

Is it possible to detect in some way whether a Clojure expression is guaranteed to be primitive?

e.g. I'd like a macro that could do this

```
(is-primitive-expression? (+ 1.0 2.0))
=> true

(is-primitive-expression? (+ 1N 2.0))
=> false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand what a primitive expression is (still reading up on it). However, I found a function from `clojure.contrib.repl-utils` called `expression-info`, that claims to return information about whether the expression is primitive or not.

See here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.repl-utils/expression-info

I simply copied the source code and tried it out, but discovered I needed to do this import first:

```
(import '(clojure.lang RT Compiler Compiler$C))
```

*However*, I tried it out with your examples, but it returned true for both (I tried quoted and unquoted expressions because I could not tell which one it required):

```
=> (expression-info (+ 1N 2.0))
=> {:class double, :primitive? true} 
=> (expression-info (+ 1.0 2.0))
=> {:class double, :primitive? true}
=> (expression-info '(+ 1.0 2.0))
=> {:class double, :primitive? true}
=> (expression-info '(+ 1N 2.0))
=> {:class double, :primitive? true}
```

Maybe some of this could provide you with useful clues/hints, but this may be very unhelpful seeing as I don't really understand what you are asking (yet).

Comment: Looking at the source of `expression-info`, it seems to return `primitive?` true or false based on whether the resulting value of the expression is primitive or not

Comment: Thanks - seems to be on the right track (although I can't find out where this function went in the new modular contrib for 1.4.....)

Comment: I ended up just copying the expression-info code into my project and it worked well - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

a macro that iterates over the form and checks the class of everything
and then verrifies that **all the symbols in the given tree are primitive types** could do the trick. You have to decide if you count things that are macros which expand to primitives as primitive and if so then macroexpand the argument first.